# Macbook Air (Mid 2012) Dual Monitor Support

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook-air

For a 2012 Macbook Air, can I hook up two external monitors?

I don't want to use the Macbook Air when its hooked up to the monitors, only the two monitors will be used.

The two external monitors both accept HDMI.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

look at section 14

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Thunderbolt-capable Macs that can support up to two connected Apple Thunderbolt Displays.

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012) and later4
- MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) and later4
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)
- MacBook Pro (15-inch and 17-inch, Early 2011) and later
- MacBook Air (Mid 2012) and later
- iMac (Late 2012)2
- iMac (Mid 2011)2
- Mac Mini (Late 2012)4
- Mac Mini (Mid 2011), 2.5 GHz3

but it seems you would need `Two Thunderbolt displays` in order to do it.  Not sure HDMI would work.  Might be able to get away with 1 thunderbolt and 1 hdmi with and adaptor

Comment: Do you think I could just get two of these? [link](http://www.amazon.ca/EnjoyGadgets-Thunderbolt-video-adapter-support/dp/B006GH8W1A)

Comment: I don't think you can use 2. AFAIK dual external monitors are done by Daisy chaining them together.  air -> TB Display 1 -> TB display 2. as there is only a single thunderbolt port on the air.    you Might be able to use that adaptor to replace TB Display 2, with the HDMI, but not sure.